# Date-based rows generation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Good day,

I have data in following form

```
ID  Start Date    End Date   
1   01-Nov-2018   01-Nov-2018
2   04-Nov-2018   07-Nov-2018
3   09-Nov-2018   09-Nov-2018
4   11-Nov-2018   12-Nov-2018
```

I want to generate the following output

```
ID  Date
1   01-Nov-2018
2   04-Nov-2018
2   05-Nov-2018
2   06-Nov-2018
2   07-Nov-2018
3   09-Nov-2018
4   11-Nov-2018
4   12-Nov-2018
```

I know how to do it if i want to process it for single ID

```
SELECT
  ,d.ID
  , dv.date_start  start_date
  , dv.date_end    End_Date
  , dv.date_start + Level - 1  the_date
From (SELECT * 
      FROM table_name d
      WHERE d.id = <some_id>) dv
Where (dv.date_start + Level - 1) <= dv.date_end
Connect By Level <= dv.date_end - dv.date_start + 1;
```

But as soon as i give multiple Ids it just goes haywire and give multiple duplicate dates. Appreciate if anyone can help in how I can generate the desired data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT id, 
       start_date + LEVEL - 1 
FROM   t 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ( end_date - start_date + 1 ) 
           AND PRIOR id = id 
                     AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL;
```

*Read* :[**Sys_Guid() in connect by level**](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=sys-guid-in-connect-by-level)

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9ef900534e66b980bfe296719d09d1e9)

Comment: Awesome, it works perfectly i did not know that i could use the id = id with prior to achieve this also, I was check that what sys_guid() does. Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f31573/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, Start_Date, End_Date ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2018-11-01', DATE '2018-11-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2018-11-04', DATE '2018-11-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2018-11-09', DATE '2018-11-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2018-11-11', DATE '2018-11-12' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.*,
       c.COLUMN_VALUE AS the_date
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT t.start_date + LEVEL - 1
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY t.start_date + LEVEL - 1 <= t.end_date
           )
           AS SYS.ODCIDATELIST
         )
       ) c
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f31573/1/0)**:

```
| ID |           START_DATE |             END_DATE |             THE_DATE |
|----|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  1 | 2018-11-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-01T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2018-11-04T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-07T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-04T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2018-11-04T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-07T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-05T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2018-11-04T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-07T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-06T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2018-11-04T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-07T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-07T00:00:00Z |
|  3 | 2018-11-09T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-09T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-09T00:00:00Z |
|  4 | 2018-11-11T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-12T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-11T00:00:00Z |
|  4 | 2018-11-11T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-12T00:00:00Z | 2018-11-12T00:00:00Z |
```